# UITableView numberOfRowsInSection section order problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am having a problem while inserting data in a table view. I have made this little example demonstrating my problem:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            NSLog(@"section: %d",section);
            if([listOfItems count]!=0){
                NSLog(@"size: %d",[listOfItems count] / 2);
                return [listOfItems count] / 2;
            }
            else{
                sectionCount++;
                NSLog(@"size: %d", [[listOfComboBoxes objectAtIndex:0] count] - 1);
                return [[listOfComboBoxes objectAtIndex:0] count] - 1;
            }
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"section: %d",section);
            NSLog(@"size: %d", [[listOfComboBoxes objectAtIndex:sectionCount++] count] - 1);
            sectionCount--;
            return [[listOfComboBoxes objectAtIndex:sectionCount++] count] - 1;
            break;
    }
}
```

This is what i receive in the log:

```
2011-06-09 11:14:40.753 TemplatesTest[1133:207] section: 3
2011-06-09 11:14:40.754 TemplatesTest[1133:207] size: 2
2011-06-09 11:14:40.754 TemplatesTest[1133:207] section: 0
2011-06-09 11:14:40.755 TemplatesTest[1133:207] size: 6
2011-06-09 11:14:40.755 TemplatesTest[1133:207] section: 1
2011-06-09 11:14:40.756 TemplatesTest[1133:207] size: 11
2011-06-09 11:14:40.756 TemplatesTest[1133:207] section: 2
2011-06-09 11:14:40.757 TemplatesTest[1133:207] size: 20
```

I am wondering why is it starting with section 3? The correct output should be (if it started with section 0):

```
section: 0
size: 6
section: 1
size: 2
section: 2
size: 11
section: 3
size: 20
```

Does anyone knows a fix?

Comment: On what did you base your statement: "the correct output should be..."? Assumption is your worst enemy when coding.

Comment: because the `listOfComboBoxes` is an `NSMutableArray` containing three `NSMutableArray`s. the count of the first one is 2, the second is 11 and the third is 20. the whole point is why is it starting with section 3.

Comment: Thats true my boss always says that to me

Comment: @robin: isn't there a fix? should i reorder my array in order to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Why is it starting with section 3? The real question is: why are you assuming that it *should* start with section zero? There is nothing in the documentation that defines the order that the method is called and so you should not make any assumptions. In current implementations it starts at the bottom of the table and works up, but, again, that's an assumption and making it could get you into trouble in the next version of iOS.

The solution is to write the method so it can return the correct result whatever the order of the requests are.

Comment: if this is the right answer. dont forget to mark it as the right one

Answer (score 1):

Why are you caring about the order in which the data source methods are called? The order in which the section details are navigated by the SDK will not affect the behavior or the interface of your app.

The non-ordered calls could probably depend on the fact that the arrays that the SDK internally uses are not ordered. But, again, you should never worry about this "issue".

You state that the correct output should be the ordered one, but why?

#### Edit

What you are doing wrong here is supposing an order to be where no-one guarantees you that. You should really implement a `switch` construct with a different `case` for each section you want to control. The data source contents do have to be deterministic, and should not change dynamically without control.

Delegating all the appearance to an autoincrementing value that updates depending on the order in which that function is called is not the way you should handle things.

Comment: @marzapower: see first comment of "Simon Lee" question.

Comment: You are doing things in a wrong way. You should never, and I say **never**, suppose to be an order in which that method is called by the SDK. You should have a `switch` with a single `case` for each different section, and not delegate everything to an `else` block. This is really a bad programming approach.

Comment: how can i implement a `switch` block if the number of sections isn't known until the parsing is finished?

Comment: You first parse the data, then you update the data source, **finally** you reload data on your table.

Comment: no i think you misunderstood... you said "You should have a `switch` with a single `case` for each different section". i cant know how many sections i will have, so i cant know how many `cases` ill have to put in my `switch` block.

Comment: one solution is to monitor the order in which the sections are created, and then populate them according this order... but this is not what i want...

Comment: If you do not know how many sections you will have, you **cannot** and **should not** load data on a table. How could you imagine this to be possible???

Comment: can you tell me why i cannot and why i should not? what should i do then?

Comment: You should learn how to program. You should: 1) collect all the data you need, 2) organize data appropriately, 3) feed the data to the data source, that will now know how it's organized (# of sections, # of rows in sections, data for each row), 4) finally update the table. If you cannot understand this, I cannot help.

Comment: i found the solution! thank you for your help, but do not tell me it is not possible or cannot be done. if you just read the question and consider yourself a programmer, you could have helped me with this issue, instead of all this talk. thank you anyway, i wasted your time

Comment: No problem. If you think you solved the problem, and you consider yourself a good programmer, please update the question with the solution. This will help me and others learn.

Comment: @Nagi it is not good form to take a bad tone with people you are asking help from. You have done it on pretty much every answer on here (including mine). Everyone has been telling you the same thing, the reason? Because we are seasoned iOS developers and we know what we are doing. If you feel you know better then you shouldn't really be asking a question in the first place.

Comment: @simon: i apologize to all. i think i got a little carried away . and with all the replies "it cant be done", "it isn't a problem"... i know **it is** a problem, and that everything **can** be done. so i cannot accept such answers. anw most of you might have misunderstood the question. i do not mind the order, all i cared about is the number of rows allocated in each section. the fix was to replace `sectionCount++` with `section-1`. you should know that i respect every one of you, but it drives me crazy when someone thinks he understands what i am talking about, but in fact he doesn't. ty

Comment: Apology accepted, misunderstandings do happen and I appreciate it can sometimes be frustrating trying to explain exactly what the issue is. Glad you got it sorted.

Comment: If you look at the answers, at your comments, and all it's clear that everyone, including me, has understood the problem in a different manner. We though you were complaining about the fact that the SDK does not sort the sections while calling your method. You, instead, just needed a solution to make the things work starting from the fact that an error was in your code and no-one noticed. No-one did because the attention was carried away. Since you solved, no problem. Remember to update the question, or to answer yourself. Our aim is to let people "evolve" and understand.

Answer (score 1):

There is no fix as this isn't a problem. The order in which the tableview requests data and draws it makes no difference to your code.

You should be using the `indexPath.section` and `indexPath.row` properties to determine what information the tableview wants.

Comment: how do you tell me this isn't a problem!!!!! for example, how do you want me to populate section 1 which has 11 rows with an array that contains 2 values... i do not always have the same number of arrays nor rows as the data is parsed from the web...

Comment: ?!?! I have a data set with 3 sections, first section has 5 rows, second has 7 and third has 2. Now tell me, how on earth does it matter WHAT order I get asked for data, you ask me for the section count for section number 3? I return 2, section 1? I return 5, section 2? I return 5. Same for the rows, you ask me for the data for section 2, row 3... not a problem! If you think this is an issue then you are not 'seeing' it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You will find the same question with extra information here

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/70913-numberofsectionsintableview-called-twice-uitableview.html

But to my assumption, UITableView creates the cell from bottom to top so that is the reason or not the delegate and datasource methods are called for rows and sections that are at the bottom of the screen and not at the end of uitableview

Edit:

May be you can calculate the number of rows before hand for each section in view did load and then just pass the value in this method

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```